# How to target the replaced content after using `replaceWith`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replacewith

I want to use Jquery (1.10.2) to replace some content on my site with the results of a API request.  Then I want to execute some more javascript on that content.  I know the new content is HTML, but I don't anything about it.  Even if it has an #id, or ".class" assocated with it, thus I cannot target the content.

jQuery.replaceWith() will return the OLD "this"; How do I get the "this" for the new content?

http://jsfiddle.net/G24X8/3/

```
$('#fix').on('click', function() {
    $('#myStuff').replaceWith("<p>Hello new world!</p>"); // Hello new world content actually comes from a server
    // since replaceWith returns the old content, how do I get the $(?this?) for the new content, when I don't know what is in it?
});
```

-daniel

Comment: See--> http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/YE37Z/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this way to get hold of the newContent after adding it to DOM, if that is what you meant:

```
$('#fix').on('click', function() {
    var $newCont = $("<p>Hello new world!</p>");
    $('#myStuff').replaceWith($newCont); 
    //Do anything with $newCont
    //$newCont.css('color', 'blue');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `.html()` instead of `.replaceWith()` -- that way you're only replacing the contents of the target tag, not the tag itself.

```
$('#fix').on('click', function() {
    $('#myStuff').html("<p>Hello new world!</p>");
    //...
    $('#myStuff').doSomethingElse(); //whatever else you need to do
});
```

Comment: I need to remove the target html <div id="mStuff"> as well.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#fix').on('click', function() {
    $('#myStuff').text('').html("<p>Hello new world!</p>");
});
```